# Rails: Adding record to a database drawing up errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging

I get this error `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` when I try to add a record to my database. I have a Track model, and a Home Controller which is supposed to facilitate the addition of a record into a database.

app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Youtube Playlist Generator</h1>

<%= form_for @track do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.text_field :youtube_url ,nil, :placeholder=>'Youtube Link Here' %>
    <%= f.submit %>         
  </p>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @track=Track.new(params[:track])
    session[:link_list] ||= []

        if params[:add] && params[:add] != ""
                session[:link_list].append(params[:add])
        end
  end 
end
```

However, Rails shoots back an error mentioned above, and mentions that the issue arises in `line 3` of the `erb` file.

If any more information is required, please let me know, I'm still feeling my way around Rails (3.2.13)

Comment: it means that `@track` is nil in the index view. You should check how it is initialized in `HomeController.index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `@track` instance variable in your `index` action of `HomeController`:

```
  @track = Track.new
```

Comment: A follow up question, look at the new HomeController. Do I need a TrackController? After I enter a value in the text field, it tells me that I have `uninitialized constant TracksController`

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice it at first. If you pass object of class `Track` to `form_for`, this method will search by default for `TracksController`. The answer is yes, you should build `TracksController` with at least `create` action.

Comment: Alright if I'm understanding you correctly, I'd create a TracksController class which would then have a create method under which I'd call `Track.new(params[:track])`, what would then be the point of `@track = Track.new` under the HomeController?

Comment: To have `Track` instance initialized in order to pass it to `form_for` helper. Thanks to this, `form_for` will automatically create proper form (including url) for creating `Track`.